# How to hibernate & switch between multiple Windows 7s?

Tags: windows, multi-boot, hibernate

Currently we are sharing a PC at home. I bought a new SSD disk and I want to encrypt it with TruCrypt (or BitLocker) & install a new Windows 7. Is it possible to see the OS selection menu when I hibernate then turn the PC on again? Or it will simply bypass the menu & resume the hibernated OS? I want to hibernate one OS and then switch to the other one.

Comment: ooh... I've never tried dual-booting with the same OS before (never had a reason to). I'm looking forward to this one. I tried to answer, but kept running into roadblocks because dual-boot Windows usually includes two different versions (one older & newer).

Comment: I want to encrypt whole disk & don't want to share the pass. So I'll split the systems.

Comment: I've got an old (3 years) Lenovo netbook here that will not go into the BIOS settings if Windows was last hibernated. It just resumes. Actually, this HP laptop does the same. It sounds similar to *Hybrid Sleep*, however I have that quite clearly disabled and I'm using a specific *Hibernate* option. In other words, I can't even get into BIOS settings, let alone any boot menu. My desktop system does let me into RAID/UEFI BIOS config, though. YMMV?

Answer (score 2):

As far as my knowledge goes, TrueCrypt provides a Hidden OS Capability, Read on it here: [Hidden OS](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=hidden-operating-system) This installs TrueCrypt's Boot Loader to the Hard Drive which can boot your system depending on the password supplied. The other functions such as hibernate etc. work as normal, it just displays a boot selection menu at system boot up. Please make sure you read the provided link thoroughly. I have personally used this on 2 Windows XP Installations, Boot XP1 on password 1 and XP2 on password 2.

Comment: Good point! I don't want others to use any password if they choose unlocked Win7.

Comment: Easy, follow procedure for creating hidden OS, but then rather than encrypting your new system, leave it unencrypted. And use the TrueCrypt Recovery Floppy to load the TC Bootloader which will then load the TrueCrypt Encrypted OS and Bypass the unencrypted system - This is a theory, I haven't tried anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

when you hipernate your operation system , it saves everything on the memory to HDD. and when you run the operation system again , the datas on the HDD (that was saved) are moved to memory again.
and when you turn on the pc the OS selection menu will be apeared

Comment: I highly suggest changing where this file is saved to.  Because this will KILL a SSD over the lifetime of the installation of Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound: That depends on the SSD.  [A forum post on Corsair](http://www.corsair.com/blog/force-series-ssd-life-testing/) had shown it took 240TB of writes to wear down a 60GB Corsair SSD.  That translates to **33 years** at 20GB/day. If you have a larger SSD, it would take even more writes.  Write limits of today's SSDs as a con are a weak debate and needs to die.